# Snowflake - multiple consumption pattern

Tags: key, cluster-computing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the best approach to take care of multiple access patterns in snowflake. For example I have a table in snowflake. One set of users query it by col1,col2,col3. So i created a cluster key on those three columns but there is another set of users who needs to query by col4. The query is performing badly with col4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One recommendation would be to create a materialized view clustered for the  alternative pattern.

Comment: Also, be sure you actually need a cluster key at all.  A 3-column cluster key is rarely beneficial unless you have a very large table.

Comment: Only problem is I guess MV will increase the cost

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted because this is probably the only option as of today. I think things will change when search optimization feature goes GA

Comment: Just remember that search optimization is limit to point queries and will not solve every performance issue.